# Invertibility of this matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, probability, random-matrices

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two stochastic matrices. Prove that $I - P_1 + P_2$ is invertible. I know that the eigenvalues of $P_1$ and $P_2$ are at most 1 in magnitude. How can I handle the difference $P_2 - P_1$ to show that the eigenvalues of $I - P_1 + P_2$ can never be zero, and thus $I - P_1 + P_2$ is invertible?

Comment: What about $P_1=I$ and $P_2$ a singular stochastic matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim isn't true.

$$\left[
\begin{array}\
  1&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
 0&0&1
\end{array}
\right]-\left[
\begin{array}\
  1&0&0\\
  0&1&0\\
 0&0&1
\end{array}
\right] +\left[
\begin{array}\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
 1&1&1
\end{array}
\right]=$$
$$ \left[
\begin{array}\
  0&0&0\\
  0&0&0\\
 1&1&1
\end{array}
\right] $$

which is not invertible.